I want to use list in Processing Python
When I use list in Processing(python),
def draw doesnt works
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y=0

def setup():
    size(500,500)
    background(255)
    balls=list()
    #balls.append(Ball(0,0))
    balls.append([0,0])
def draw():
    background(255)
    for b in balls:
        fill(0)
        circle(b[0],b[1],20)

I tried to find the cause, When I do list indexing, Processing didnt work

What does it mean "doesn't work"? Also, you might want to take a look at Staging Ground

Looks like an issue of variable namespaces to me.

Why do you have a Ball class and store the balls as lists in a list? Do you actually mean balls.append(Ball(0, 0)) and circle(b.x, b.y, 20)? Why does the constructor have two parameters if you don't use them?

this looks like you try to define methods for your class but you define functions instead. and your code is not complete as you do not show object ? size and background ? so it is difficult to help. balls should be defined and init as self.balls for the class

@Malo "this looks like you try to define methods for your class" Why? I see one class and two free functions. Nothings looks like the functions should be methods. "and your code is not complete as you do not show object ?" What object? Your comment makes no sense.

@jabaa : ok it would probably be logical to have a Ball and a BallList object, it would make more sense.

@Malo Why do you need a BallList object? The OP wants free functions.

@jabaa you see the OP defines class Ball but do not use it ... OP code is not complete ... difficult to sees exactly what OP wants and to make it clean code or just use a plain list.

This is a simple scoping issue. If you declare a variable inside a function you can't use it outside:
def f():
   x = 2
f()
print(x) # error, the variable x only exists inside the function

To fix, simply declare the balls variable outside the function:
balls=[]

def setup():
    size(500,500)
    background(255)
    #balls.append(Ball(0,0))
    balls.append([0,0])

Alternatively, you can use the global keyword to mark the variable as global:
def setup():
    global balls
    size(500,500)
    background(255)
    #balls.append(Ball(0,0))
    balls.append([0,0])

If you want to clear the list of balls inside setup() you can use:
balls[:] = []

Note that
balls=[]

Will not work since it will just create a new local variable instead of modifying the global one. Unless you use the global keyword then it will work again.

this is not a simple scoping issue, it is more an method issue, as you defiuned functions instead of class methods

@Malo That is incorrect. Scoping works the same in methods as in normal functions, (unless you use self.). There is no indication that these functions where ment to be methods

@mousetail Your implementation of setup isn't quite equivalent to the OPs, since it doesn't clear the current list of balls.

you can use self.balls to have a variable accessible in the whole object

@Malo Why would a Ball instance contain a list of self.balls? That makes no sense.

IMH : it would make more sense and be cleaner to have a Ball class and a BallList Class, and to go full OOP rather than mixing 1 Class and several methods.

@Malo You could argue about the best way to arcitecture this code all day, but that is not what OP is asking.

@Malo That's your opinion. There are many reasons to not go full OOP.

I guess what you want is circle(b[0].x, b[0].y, 20).

This is incorrect, the b object is in the form [x,y] already where x and y are numbers not ball objects. This is unrelated to the issue, which is that the balls list doesn't exist in the correct scope

From what I read on various pages, the syntax is circle(a, b, extent), so separate parameters for the center point.

In the current code, b is a list containing two numbers. b[0].x and b[0].y won't work, because numbers don't have x and y properties.

@jabaa, you're right. I was too fast with that one. Nevertheless I think that the OP meant to use the x and y values of the Ball object and erroneously coded them as [0] and [1] instead of x and y .

But b is not a Ball object. #balls.append(Ball(0,0)) is commented out.

You coud go this way
use balls as a parameter of the functions.
(or other possibility is to try to create a BallList object)
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y=0

def setup(balls):
    #size(500,500)
    #background(255)
    balls.append([0,0])

def draw(balls):
    #background(255)
    for b in balls:
        #fill(0)
        #circle(b[0],b[1],20)
        pass

balls = []

setup(balls)
draw(balls)


Why would a ball contain multiple balls? That seems like a weired name for a class if it's meant to be a collection of balls rather than a single balll

I agree, but code shown in not complete, so we have to guess. Maybe rename Ball > BallCollection or something, OP should give more details and working code. see [MRE]

A ball collection would not have an x and a y. The Ball class in OP's example is clearly meant to be a sperate ball the the list is a seperate. Especailly considering the commented out Ball constructor

The code in the question contains one class with two properties and two free functions. Why have you moved the free functions into the class? That makes no sense. What does self.balls = [0,0] mean? Why does a Ball have a list of balls that contains two numbers? It should be clear that you've misunderstood the question. You had to comment out half of the code.

IMH : it would make more sense and be cleaner to have a Ball class and a BallList Class, and to go full OOP rather than mixing 1 Class and several methods.

@jabaa ok i changed to use a simple list and functions with parameters wich is probably what OP was trying to do first.

Now, you've still commented out half of the code. "Your implementation of setup isn't quite equivalent to the OPs, since it doesn't clear the current list of balls."

you can use balls.extend to get the result you want.
Balls only gets one item, b[0] is your list [0,0], so b[1] doesn't make sense.

This is incorrect, b is a single item in the balls list so it will have two items

balls=[[0,0]], b=[0,0] so b[0] make sense, doesn't it?

True, if its contained in the class it should be referenced with self.b as well. The question is flagged for quality
